# viewModel in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, viewmodel

I'm trying to understand view models using kotlin for android, and I'm running into some difficulty. I have a very simple dummy app which allows a user to increment a number and then send that number to a second screen. That second screen will then display a random number between 0 and the sent number.

Here is the problem.

I understand how to send the data from the first page to the second using intents, and I know how to make a viewmodel in the second page. However, if I send the intent and then set the viewmodel equal to the set intent, it doesnt function properly. Rotating the screen will cause the intent to be resent and the viewmodel doesnt maintain the state of the data (the number rerandomizes).

Ideally, I'd like to just be able to just update the viewModel class in place of sending the intent, but the instance of the class is created when the second page is created, so that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Based on the google codelabs "build my first android app" tutorial.

Here's my code; first page:

```
package com.example.patientplatypus.babbysfirstandroidapp

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.view.Window
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.Toast

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.textView
import org.jetbrains.anko.db.PRIMARY_KEY
import org.jetbrains.anko.db.UNIQUE
import org.jetbrains.anko.db.createTable
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.startActivity
import com.example.patientplatypus.babbysfirstandroidapp.R.id.textView
import org.jetbrains.anko.db.*
import org.jetbrains.anko.indeterminateProgressDialog

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    fun toastMe(view: View) {
        val myToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Hello Toast!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        myToast.show()
    }

    fun countMe (view: View) {
        Log.d("insideCountMeCheck", "hey you are inside count me!")
        val countString = textView.text.toString()
        var count: Int = Integer.parseInt(countString)
        count++
        textView.text = count.toString()
    }

    fun randomMe (view: View) {
        val randomIntent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
        val countString = textView.text.toString()
        val count = Integer.parseInt(countString)
        randomIntent.putExtra(SecondActivity.TOTAL_COUNT, count.toString())
        startActivity(randomIntent)
    }
}
```

Here's my code, second page:

```
package com.example.patientplatypus.babbysfirstandroidapp

import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.view.Window
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.Toast
import java.util.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_second.randomText

class CountViewModel : ViewModel() {
     var TOTAL_COUNT = "total_count"
}

class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var countModel: CountViewModel

    companion object {
        const val TOTAL_COUNT = "total_count"
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)
        countModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CountViewModel::class.java)
        countModel.TOTAL_COUNT = intent.getStringExtra(TOTAL_COUNT)
        displayForRandomNum(countModel.TOTAL_COUNT);
        showRandomNumber()

    }

    fun showRandomNumber() {
        val count = countModel.TOTAL_COUNT.toInt()
        val random = Random()
        var randomInt = 0
        if (count > 0) {
            randomInt = random.nextInt(count + 1)
        }
        Log.d("randomFinal", Integer.toString(randomInt))
        displayForRandomNum(Integer.toString(randomInt))
    }

    fun displayForRandomNum(totalCount: String){
        randomText.text = totalCount
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know that I understand. I thought the point of the `viewModel` was that I didn't have to bother with lifecycle hooks because it *shouldn't* destroy the data every time the activity dies. Can you show me a very simple example? EDIT: Also, ideally I don't want to use getIntent() at all - I just want to save it entirely in viewModel.

Comment: ViewModels aren't shared across activities - they're only for within one Activity.

Answer (score 0):

An orientation change causes the activity be destroyed then recreated. This means `onCreate` will be called on every rotate. The same intent that started the activity originally would still be available to it. So `intent.getStringExtra(TOTAL_COUNT)` would return the original value from the intent that start the activity every time the screen is rotated. `ViewModel` will retain the data through the rotation though.

Your issue is that your overriding you're ViewModel's`TOTAL_COUNT` with the original value from the intent every time. What you can do is check that the `TOTAL_COUNT` value isn't `"total_count"` (meaning its already been set from the intent) before setting it in `onCreate`.

Comment: I've tried this         `if(countModel.TOTAL_COUNT == "total_count") {
            countModel.TOTAL_COUNT = intent.getStringExtra(TOTAL_COUNT)
        }` and all this causes is for it to hang and not rotate properly. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. https://imgur.com/a/GuG9r

Comment: Not sure why that would make it hang. I'd debug it and step through the `onCreate` and see what's slow.